# Entering views result to field through rules

Tags: 7, views, rules, organic-groups

When I create a new OG, I would like the user with the least number of OG subscriptions automatically to be added to this group. So I created a views block where I count and least the user with the least number of OG subscriptions. Under actions, there is an option named `subscribe user to group`. Is there a way for me to use the views result in data selector of this action? Otherwise, how would you tackle this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a sql query through the [Views Rules module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_rules) and it did the trick.